# Form submit function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

This is my basic html page.

```
<html>
    <head>        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>       
    </head> 

    <body >        
        <form id="#forgotform">
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required="required" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>               
    </body>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#forgotform').on('submit', function() {
            alert('You submitted the form!');
        });
    });
    </script>  

</html>
```

I am trying to do something on submit form #forgotform, but it is not even triggering an alert on submitting the form. Please help me out.

Answer (score 4):

replace `<form id="#forgotform">` this with `<form id="forgotform">`.May be this will work.

Comment: # is used by jquery  to pick element ids from the DOM. Element id shouldn't contain # itself.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '#' from the `<form id="#forgotform">`. There is no need to put '#' while adding id to an element in HTML.

Answer (score -2):

You can also try this

```
$("#form-id").submit(function(){
    alert("Submitted");
});
```

Your HTML Form

```
<form id="form-id">..</form>
```

Comment: In jQuery put your form id :-
  $("#form-id").submit()

Comment: just replace $("form") to $("#your Form id")